# CE v1.9.3.4 (v2) did NOT fix the "Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout" Was released July 12,2017

Tags: checkout, code, magento1.9.3, paypal-standard, form-key

@Ryan-hoerr YESTERDAY sent out message that there was v2 Patch or upgrade  to `v1.9.3.4 from v1.9.3.3` because of the `form_key` checkout problem which the Magento CE 1.9.3.4 Release Notes was supposed to address.

"...changed how Magento validates form keys during the generic five-step checkout process. Previously, customer registration failed during standard checkout processing if form key authentication was enabled."

However after upgrading the `v1.9.3.4` did NOT fix or change the checkout process issue Im seeing. i.e. when anyone tries to check out as Guests/ or Registration form still cant get past initial page for registration i.e. wont change pages and stays on page one on checkout with Enable Form Key Validation "On" at Checkout. It stays on same page and if set to 'no" will go through all 6 form pages but wont send form to PayPal. (Im using Standard PayPal checkout API).

It will take too long to wait for patch (v3?) and Im unable to have a single checkout on this live site. Read way too many comments that talked about other bugs, or other versions, mostly using hours and read through them all. So far there were no clear and specific answers or addressing this as a work around.

I just need the specific 
1) path/location to fix this in V1.9.3.4 and

2) what specifically in the code that must be commented out (or added or whatever) so I can get this live site running again. If your guessing then please dont respond as there is a fix that does work (according to @Ryan-hoerr message who appears to have worked on it) That specific change to get it to work is what I do need. Thanks ahead of time for your help.

EDIT: to be clear I would like to NOT have to roll back to v.1.7.0.2 but will if no solution for this v1.9.3.4 checkout problem is presented that works. If v1.7.0.2 will still function with PayPal new security requirements started June 30 then that would be best option.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested V2 path on 1.7/1.8 and it works like a gem, customer CAN register accounts during checkout, the checkout fully gets processed, and orders complete.

For now, try to disable FORM KEY authentication see if you can complete checkout.

If you are stuck at registration page and cannot proceed to other checkout steps, maybe there is a problem in form-key missing.

Nevertheless its hard to provide any answers as we do not see the error logs nor access to the server.

Comment: I had v1.7.0.2 never had any problems...as stated in my question. I "upgraded from v.1.7.0.2 to v1.9.3.3 checkout issues started then "upgraded" again to 1.9.3.4 was SUPPOSED to address but has not. So why are you talking about v.1.7 / 1.8 are you saying forget v.1.9.3.4 and roll back to my saved v1.7.0.2 backup and forget "upgrading"? I will if no one knows answer the question about v1.9.3.4 which as described in my question does NOT work in v.1.9.3.4. It sounds like our telling me to abandon v1.9.3.4 and use my backup to restore to v.1.7.0.2.

Comment: Just tried the 1.9.3.4 version and checkout works fine. During your update something must have happened. Again, hard to tell without looking through files as your issue is very case based. I would revert to 1.7.0.2 and then update to 1.9.3.4 (skip 1.9.3.3). Also test on test site first.

Comment: Plus updating from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.4 is a huge jump, 4 years of updates to magento. Careful with such updates, must debug everything first before applying to live on live site.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion...I used Softalisous for the updating and confirmed successful to 1.9.3.3. and had option to go to 1.8 but I took the big jump which maybe was too much. But everything else worked except checkout which took a while to know about that issue...read about fix in 1.9.3.4 and upgraded but same issue. I will be trying that 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.4 OR maybe first to 1.8 . It might work and will try it today. If not will have to stick with 1.7.0.2

Comment: What else could possibly be is one of your old 1.7.0.2 3rd party extensions that may associate with checkout is interfering 1.9.3.4 checkout process.